# Prove that if the order of a set H is co-prime to the index of N in G then H is a sub group of N

Tags: group-theory

$ G $ is a finite group. $H \le G \ ; N\unlhd G$ if $|H| $ is coprime to $[G : N]$ then $H \le N$

first:
if $\pi: G \to \frac{G}{N}$ then $\pi (H) $ is a subgroup of $\frac{G}{N}$
by Lagrange's theorem: $|\pi (H)|$ divides $\frac{G}{N}$
$\pi (H)$ is the image of $ H $ by $ \pi $ 
By the first Isomorphism theorem: 
[image of $\pi {]} \cong \frac{H}{kern(\pi )} $
Second: 
$|\pi (H)| \ | \ |H|$ since image $\pi \cong \frac{H}{kern(\pi )} $
So $|\pi (H)|$ divides $ [G:N] \ $ & $ |\pi(H)| $ divides $ |H| \ ; |H|$ is coprime to $[G:N]$
I think I'm missing something because I should beable to conclude $H \le N$ but don't see it.
(guess $ \frac{|H|}{|N|} | \frac{|G|}{|N|} \ ; \frac{|H|}{|N|} | |H| $ so $ H | N$ )

Comment: Well, you can conclude that $|\pi(H)|=1$, as $|\pi(H)|\mid\gcd(|H|,[G:N])=1$.

Comment: so then $ ker(\pi) = H $ so wouldn't $N \le H$ not the other way around ? @Element118

Comment: No. Note that a subgroup of $N$ would map to the identity, since every element in $N$ maps to the identity via the homomorphism $\pi$.